# How to implement and test Firebase Analytics in a React-Native project?

Tags: firebase, google-analytics, react-native, firebase-analytics

I have learned from reading that Firebase officially supports react-native.

https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html

I have followed the above link and performed these steps:

1. `npm install firebase --save`
2. Opened `index.ios.js` and imported firebase

> import * as firebase from 'firebase';

3. Initialise Firebase

```js
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "<your-api-key>",
  authDomain: "<your-auth-domain>",
  databaseURL: "<your-database-url>",
  storageBucket: "<your-storage-bucket>",
  ,
};
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
```

I have put all the right values in the above fields. From my understanding, this should enable Firebase analytics in my project and I should see session reporting in Firebase console. But I can't see anything.

Am I missing anything here? Also is there any way to get Firebase logs in react native so that I can know what's happening?

Comment: For Firebase' Database logging, you can switch it on with: `firebaseApp.database.enableLogging(true);`

Answer (score 3):

The Firebase web SDK (including real-time database) works with React Native. However, Firebase does not currently offer analytics as part of the Web SDK. To enable analytics, you would need to implement a wrapper around the native SDKs or use a library such as https://github.com/fullstackreact/react-native-firestack.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics sends info every 24 hours.
you can enable Logcat for Firebase to check you're calls, add in terminal,
and check it out in Android Studio logcat:

> `adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
>   adb shell setprop log.tag.FA-SVC VERBOSE
>   adb logcat -v time -s FA FA-SVC`

And to see them right away in the Firebase console you should enable debug mode - that sends them right away:

> To enable Analytics Debug mode on an Android device, execute the following commands:
>
> `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>`
>
> This behavior persists until you explicitly disable Debug mode by executing the following command:
>
> `adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app .none.`

[checkout the Firebase documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/)